# Why is surface gravity named this way?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, event-horizon, vector-fields

I've come across two definitions of surface gravity.

1. We look at the killing horizon of a Killing vector field $\xi$ and we find from the definition that  $\xi_\nu \nabla^\nu \xi^\mu = \kappa \xi^\mu$. This scalar $\kappa$ is called ***"Surface Gravity"***.
2. In Rindler spacetime the timelike killing vector field is given as $K^\mu = V U^\mu$. Where $U^\mu$ is the 4-velocity of the observer. Then $V =\sqrt{-K^\mu K_\mu}$ is called "redshift factor" and $\sqrt{\nabla_\mu V \nabla^\mu V}$ is called the ***"Surface Gravity"***.

My question is two-fold.

- A.  What's the relation between these two definitions.
- B.  Why is this scalar named surface gravity?

I've seen the question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/232157/) and the answer. Although helpful this does not address my questions directly.